# correct way to include an external HTML page in WP-admin

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add a page that I have already to appear in the WP-admin, so I added a new item to WP admin menu

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');
 
function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', ' add conent', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
}
 
function test_init(){
    //echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
    echo file_get_contents("..\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\\form2.php");

}
```

Notice here in my test_init I just throw the file via file_get_contents

And my form2 file contents HTML headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.0/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.0/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<style>
 ...
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML for FORM code goes here -->
</body>
```

Now my 2 questions are :

<s>1-Is this the right way to do this? is there any WordPress-ish way to do this properly using `file_get_contents` won't execute the PHP parts of the file (HTML code printed with a PHP loop)...</s>

2-Also, does the fact that my custom HTML/PHP file has some styles and JS imported on its own cause any conflict with the entire site and the theme? or are these only used locally in the context of the form?

*Edit: based on the comments, `include` will do the job for question 1, and as I suspected having nested HTML tags is indeed a bad idea, so I need to remove body, HTML, head tags, etc and leave the form only but how do I include style and script tags only for this particular page and not the entire site if I remove the head tags? In HTML it is not a good practice to put the style tag (and `<link rel="stylesheet"`) in the body  and I don't want to slow down the entire site by using enqueue and adding the JS/CSS files everywhere*

Comment: `file_get_contents` won't execute any PHP code in that file, and you'll have nested HTML tags and body tags. It's also bad practice and insecure to make direct requests to PHP files in your plugin/theme from a browser, be that for form handling or for AJAX/JS requests

Comment: @TomJNowell ,  Thanks for the comment. I sort of had doubts about everything you mentioned, therefore the question... Any  ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this properly? I guess I should start by stripping the external file from body and headed tags, but in that case, how do I add styles for that form only?

Comment: Do people who develop plugins with complex pages in WP_admin really throw all their HTML inside an echo in the same file ?! I am sure they divide things between files...

Comment: “ does the fact that my custom HTML/PHP file has some styles and JS imported on its own cause any conflict with the entire site and the theme” Yes, it will cause conflicts with the WordPress admin.

Comment: @user206904 You can include HTML/PHP from other files with `include`. That’s basic PHP and it works the same with WordPress.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thanks! Care to write an answer?  `Include` will do the job indeed, totally forgot about it for some reason. That said, still does not answer the question about custom JS/bootstrap, how to avoid conflicts? anyway for that? or  I just arbitrarily make sure there are no name collisions and use the regular enqueue?
I don't want to include things in the entire site for visitors and authors just for 1 form that appears to a specific level of admins...

Comment: sometimes there won't be a way to have both your bootstrap etc JS and the WP Admin JS at the same time, not without changing what your pages JS is. How you resolve that conflict is going to depend on what the conflict is and we'd need to see your output. At this point you should just try it and see instead of speculating, you're still trying to make the most of doing things in a way that isn't ideal and causes issues ( the standalone HTML/PHP file ). If instead you had just the form part and included that, and then used a shortcode/block/widget on the frontend it would be dramatically easier

Comment: Remember, WP is a CMS, so all requests are supposed to go through WordPress. Bypassing that with standalone files that handle/display things like forms/etc or standalone HTML files is going to cause problems like this, then make solving them harder, but it's easily avoided